# video from sony nex5 camera garbled

Tags: hdvideo

I take video on the camera in high definition mode. I then transfer the file to my computer. It takes MTS file format video. When i try to view the video on my computer using VLC I get some video which sticks while the sound plays more or less fine. The video then jumps ahead sporadically. Does anyone have any ideas how I can get to see the video properly

Answer (score 1):

VLC does not support AVCHD fully which is the codec that most consumer HD camcorders record in.

The only solution I know of is to install the [K-Lite codec pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) which has a good AVCHD codec. This is available on [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) for easy installation.

Comment: codec packs are typically a bad choice - do you know of any other sources of the AVCHD codec?

Comment: @Mala - They have improved drastically over the last few years. It is the only good solution I know other than to purchase a Blu ray player program such as PowerDVD which includes AVCHD codec - That being said, anything/most recording devices usually come with software that allows you to play the content - or some sort of codec. I would advise trying to use that... If you trust a CD that came from Sony!

Comment: Interesting. Once the codec pack is installed, will VLC be able to play the file?

Comment: Thanks Wil...problem solved with downloaded K-Lite codec pack on Ninite